# Entity Framework - Foreign Key Object not mapped on Abstract Class

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have my Emprunt Class, which have a foreign key on a Client Class and Item Class (this one is abstract). When I try to get my Emprunt from database I can access my Client but not my Item (i have this following error : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.").

```
public List<Emprunt> GetEmpruntsUsers(Client client)
        {
            var query = from emprunt in Emprunts
                        where emprunt.Client.ID == client.ID
                        select emprunt;
            var empruntsUser = query.ToList();

            Console.WriteLine(empruntsUser[0].Client.Nom); //works
            Console.WriteLine(empruntsUser[0].Item.Nom); //this is where i'm getting the error
            Console.ReadLine();


            return empruntsUser;
        }
```

[image]
Emprunt.cs

```
public class Emprunt
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Client Client { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Item Item { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime Date_Emprunt { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime Date_Max_Rendu { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Client")]
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Item")]
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
    }
```

Client.cs

```
public class Client : User
    {
        public ICollection<Emprunt> Emprunts { get; set; }
    ...
    }
```

User.cs

```
public abstract class User
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Nom { get; set; }
        public string Prenom{ get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Age { get; set; }
    ...
    }
```

Item.cs

```
public abstract class Item
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Nom { get; set; }
        public int MaxDays { get; set;  }

        public ICollection<Emprunt> Emprunts { get; set; }
    ...    
   }
```

Does somebody have a solution from my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF does not support abstract class, they must be implemented, like your other abstract class user is implemented as client.